# Are the 2-adic valuations for $2^{-n/m}$ algebraically reliable?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Interpret each of the base $p$ Lyndon Words $W$ of length $n$ as a base $p$ number and let it represent the $p-$adic number which it naturally represents:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}p^{kn}W$

So e.g. $1_2$ represents the number $-1$ and $01_2$ represents $-\frac13$

The function $x\mapsto(x-2^{\nu_2(x)})$ acts on 2-adic numbers by orbiting the cycles of each Lyndon word if we give ourselves a little leeway in ignoring some trailing zeroes.

Letting $m$ count the number of $1$'s in any base $2$ Lyndon word, then $f(x)=\dfrac{x-2^{\nu_2(x)}}{2^{n/m}}$ deals with any trailing zeroes such that $f$ is now periodic with $f^m(x)=x$ **provided the 2-adic valuations are reliable**.

By $\nu_2(x)$ being "algebraically reliable" I mean for all possible valuations $\nu$ then $f(\nu x)=\nu f(x)$.  Note that $f$ is a special case of $ax+b$.

**Question**

Are these 2-adic valuations for $2^{-n/m}$ algebraically reliable?

I've seen extensions I think for $2^{-1/2^n}$ and for roots of unity but I don't know how far this principle extends and whether it extends to $p^{-n/m}$.

EDIT

I have this much which I need to parse:

> an element $α$ whose minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q_2$ has degree $d$ is given the value $|N_{\mathbb{Q}_2(\alpha)|\mathbb{Q}_2}(\alpha)|^{1/d}$. This is treated extensively in any book on p-adics, local fields etc.

From this, I think if $x=2^{m/n}$ then its minimal polynomial is the unique irreducible monic polynomial of smallest degree $p(x)$ with rational coefficients such that $p(x)=0$ and whose leading coefficient is $1$.

So if I simplify initially to find for $m=1$ then by Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion I think I want $\alpha$ to be the solution to a polynomial $x^n-p$, i.e. $x^n-2$.

But then I can't parse $|N_{\mathbb{Q}_2(\alpha)|\mathbb{Q}_2}(\alpha)|^{1/d}$

Comment: What does it mean for a valuation to be "(algebraically) reliable"?

Comment: The more general question of whether they are reliable for algebra I guess is something like asking whether affine transformations on $\Bbb Z_2$ regularised by a quotient map to $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ so e.g. of the form $g(x)=ax+b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ commute with valuations by which I mean $2^vg(x)=g(2^vx)$.for all valid valuations $v$.

Comment: ...looking at that last definition, I already had some doubts it would hold but it now looks like my question is asking about some injectivity property of valuations or their inverse.

Comment: You are asking if something is *algebraically reliable*, a concept you invented and whose meaning you yourself do not seem to be so sure about — you guess —  and you were hoping to sidestep it? The idea was for people to guess?

Comment: I read three times what you wrote and I cannot make sense of any single sentence.

Comment: All mimsy were the borogoves, and the mome raths outgrabe.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez now you're not being very nice. Is that deliberate, and is there a reason why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is mostly noise.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks at least for giving a reason.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want something like: For any $a, b \in K$, the function $f: x \mapsto ax + b p^{v_p(x)}$ "should" satisfy

$$f(\color{red}{p^{\frac{m}{n}}} x) \stackrel{?}= \color{red}{p^{\frac{m}{n}}} f(x).$$

To make you aware of a big problem in this:

Good news: The standard $p$-adic valuation $v_p : \mathbb Q_p \rightarrow \mathbb Z \cup \{\infty\}$, and $p$-adic absolute value $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p : \mathbb Q_p \rightarrow p^{\mathbb Z} \cup  \{0\}$, extend uniquely all the way up to $\mathbb C_p$. We get maps

$v_p : \mathbb C_p \rightarrow \mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$, and

$\lvert \cdot \rvert_p : \mathbb C_p \rightarrow p^{\mathbb Q} \cup  \{0\}$.

But beware very bad news: This last codomain $p^{\mathbb Q}$ is a subset of the **real numbers** $\mathbb R$. In particular, while

$$v_p (\color{red}{p^{\frac{m}{n}}}x) = \frac{m}{n} + v_p(x)$$

holds true if $\color{red}{p^{\frac{m}{n}}}$ denotes **any of the (up to $n$ distinct) elements of $K$ whose $n$-th power is $p^m$**, to write

$$ \lvert \color{red}{p^{\frac{m}{n}}} x \rvert_p = \color{blue}{p^{-\frac{m}{n}}} \lvert x \rvert_p,$$

as true and tempting as it is, is extremely treacherous. Because: The red $p^{\frac{m}{n}}$, as said, can stand for any of the up to $n$ elements $\color{red}{\text{in } K}$ such that (...), while the blue $p^{\frac{m}{n}}$ denotes the **unique (if $n$ is even: unique positive) number $\color{blue}{\text{in }\mathbb R}$** whose $n$-th power is $p^m$. Those red numbers have very little in common with that blue number, as we are in the trap exposed in my little essay [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4007515/96384).

To pin it down: To even think that writing $$x \mapsto p^{v_p(x)}$$ defines a map, as soon as the valuation $v_p$ takes non-integer values, runs into a problem:

- If we mean it as a map $K \rightarrow \mathbb R$, (which in standard notation one would write $x \rightarrow \lvert x \rvert_p^{-1}$), then its codomain is not its domain. Which implies that you cannot compose it with itself, i.e. expressions like $f^{\circ k}$ make no sense. Neither would something like $\color{red}{ax+b}\color{blue}{p^{\frac{m}{n}}}$, because $a,x,b \in K$ while $p^{\frac{m}{n}} \in \mathbb R$.
- If we mean it as a map $K \rightarrow K$, i.e. want $K$ to be the codomain, then it is not clear which of the up to $n$ elements in $K$ we would mean by writing "$p^{\frac{m}{n}}$". And even if we somehow agree on choices here, such a "re-interpreted" value map **would no longer share any of the useful properties of the actual absolute value $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p$** (I am not even sure if one could make such a choice multiplicative, in any case the triangle inequality can not even be stated now!)

Comment: Thanks. I think you've understood what I want correctly. I was hoping this problem didn't exist, but I was also aware that if it does, the Lyndon words have some algebraic properties which might give us natural choices for our valuation. E.g. they factor and form a free group and a free lie algebra. For now i will digest the reasons for the problem.

Comment: Having partially digested your linked answer... The problem appears to be a matter of how do we canonical "choose" which root to use. I only need valuations to behave nicely within the same orbit of $f$. Since each orbit of $f$ contains only rotations of the same Lyndon word, I wonder if the ordered ring property of the Lyndon words informs that choice?

Comment: I will give you a connection between my question and your answer. If an eventually periodic p-adic number is of the form $2^t+u$ with $t$ the periodic part, one is unable to give a canonical value for $t$. But if $t$ is a repeating Lyndon word, this now identifies a canonical $t,u$ in every instance. I am inquiring whether this helps us to solve the problem you are describing.

Comment: ok next thing I (think I) see is I am only concerned with the root of unity subsets of $\Bbb C$ so I am making a connection between the $n-$periodic Lyndon words and the $n^{th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: ok digesting a little further - where you write "true if $p^{m/n}$ denotes any of the **(up to $n$ distinct) elements** of $K$ whose $n$-th power is $pm$, to write..."  In the question I ask, we can actually identify a unique such element of $K$, i.e. the one which is chosen in accordance with the rotational position of the number's Lyndon word. So e.g. $\overline{01}_2$ will associate with $1$ and $\overline{10}_2$ will associate with $-1$

Comment: No clue what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you understand that $\overline{01}_2=-\frac13$ is congruent to the Lyndon word $01$, while on the other hand $\overline{10}_2=-\frac23$ is congruent to $10$ which is one of its rotations, and which is not a Lyndon word?

Comment: Yes, but not how that relates to what I wrote ...

Comment: ok. I just want to pick values for $2^{m/n}$ that make my $f$ periodic of order $m$, if and only if it is orbiting a repeating lyndon word of length $n$ and having $m$ ones in it. For example $f(x)=\dfrac{x-2^{\nu_2(x)}}{2^{n/m}}$ is periodic of order $1$ on the string $\overline{01}_2$ because $2^{n/m}=4$. I'm still trying to work out from your answer if it tells me an arbitrary choice of $2^{n/m}$ fails for my particular case. (By particular case, I mean my $f$ over all repeating base $2$ Lyndon words.) If arbitrary chouces fail, I think the Lyndon words give us a way of resolving that.