# What is $17$ adic value of $3+2\sqrt{-2}\in \Bbb{Q}_{17}$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

What is $17$ adic value of $3+2\sqrt{-2}\in \Bbb{Q}_{17}$ ?
I expanded $\sqrt{-2}=7+a_117+・・・$, so $3+2\sqrt{-2}=17+{a_1}17+・・・=17(1+a_1+a_{2}17＋・・・)$, thus $ord_{17}(3+2\sqrt{-2})\ge 1$.

If $ord_{17}(3+2\sqrt{-2})\ge 2$, $a_1$ should be $16$, but if so, $(7+16・17＋・・・)^2≡-2mod289$, then $7×17×2×16≡-51mod289$. This is contradiction.

Thus, I conclude $ord_{17}(3+2\sqrt{-2})= 1$.

Am I thinking too hard? I would appreciate it if you could tell me if there is a simpler way to calculate it.

Comment: By a fondamental property we have $$|3+2\sqrt{-2}|_{17}\le \max\{|3|_{17},|2|_{17}\cdot|\sqrt{-2}|_{17}\}=\max\{1,|\sqrt{-2}|_{17}\}$$ so your true  problem is to calculate $|\sqrt{-2}|_{17}$ and you are done.

Comment: Note that the answer depends on making the choice that the symbol $\sqrt{-2}$ in $\mathbb Z_{17}$ should denote specifically the square root that is $\equiv 7$ mod $17$. A priori there is no reason why we should not call $\sqrt{-2}$ the one which is $\equiv 10$ mod $17$, and for that we get a different answer. Compare no. 3 in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4007515/96384.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After knowing $\sqrt{-2}=7+a_1p+\cdots\ \ (p=17)$, we see
$$\nu_{17}(3+2\sqrt{-2})=\nu_{17}(17+2a_1p+\cdots)\geqq 1$$
and
$$\nu_{17}(3-2\sqrt{-2})=\nu_{17}(-11-2a_1p-\cdots)=0,$$
but these two numbers multiply to $17=p$, so
$$\nu_{17}(3+2\sqrt{-2})+\nu_{17}(3-2\sqrt{-2})=\nu_{17}((3+2\sqrt{-2})(3-2\sqrt{-2}))=\nu_{17}(17)=1,$$
hence $\nu_{17}(3+2\sqrt{-2})=1$ follows.

EDIT: In fact, the computation of $\nu_{17}(3-2\sqrt{-2})$ was unnecessary, just knowing it is $\geq 0$ (which follows from $\sqrt{-2}\in \mathbb{Z}_{17}$, at once) was enough.