# Is it possible to represent imaginary numbers as dozadic or p-adic numbers?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I only just learned about dozadic and p-adic numbers after watching a YouTube video. I found it interesting that negative numbers and real numbers could be represented by an infinitely long positive integer. Which made me wonder, could imaginary numbers also be represented as 10-adic or p-adic number? What would be the dozadic equivalent of i1?

Comment: When $p\equiv 1\pmod 4,$ yes.

Comment: And they aren't "infinitely long positive integers." It is unwise t9 think of them as positive. They **look** positive, but $p$-adic numbers are not naturally ordered.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews To be careful: $i$ can be defined in the $p$-adics when $p\equiv1\pmod4$, but that doesn't imply that every purely imaginary number can be (much less every complex number).

Comment: Most real numbers can*not* be naturally represented as $p$-adic numbers (or the other way around). https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4007515/96384 What Thomas Andrews means above is that the equation $x^2+1=0$ has two solutions in $\mathbb Q_p$ for $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$. It is potentially unwise to call these solutions $\pm i$ though, or to conflate them with the imaginary unit and its conjugate in $\mathbb C$. They only behave like those algebraically.

Comment: Right. The reals and the $p$-adics, for all the so-many primes $p$, not only don’t correspond with each other, each of them is completely ignorant of the existence of the others.